# call perl script from shell script with two arguments 1) filename and 2)array of integers

Tags: perl, shell

I want to call perl script which scans a file for processing from shell script.
Perl script is using two arguments 1) File name 2) Array of integers 
I need to know how should I call(Syntax) perl script from shell script with two arguments 1) String 2) Array

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You don't need to do anything special.  Just send all arguments as a space separated list.

Answer (score 0):

If the perl script you're calling is expecting the integer array in one argument, you probably have to quote it accordingly to the shell you're using. So put it in double quotes for Windows' cmd.exe and in single or double quotes for about any other shell.

E.g.:
`perl yourscript.pl filename.txt "1 2 3 4"` for cmd.exe

or

`yourscript.pl filename.txt '1 2 3 4'` for bash, Powershell, etc.

Otherwise the integer arguments arrive one at a time in perl, instead of a single argument.

Comment: Thanks. I created array variable and passed as an argument it worked.